# Coalescing the memory and dealing with pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

In the following code, I don't know why I never enter the if. It makes sense to me that it goes inside the if:

```
void Mem_Coalesce(){


    list_t* temp;
    temp = freep;
        if(free_node_count == 2){
        //will finish
             printf("Addr of temp is  %llx\n\n", (long long unsigned) temp);
                 printf("Size of Temp is  %d\n\n", temp->size);
             printf("Addr of end of temp free node space is  %llx\n\n", (long long unsigned) ((char*)temp + temp->size));
             printf("Addr of start temp->next  is  %llx\n\n", (long long unsigned) temp->next);
        if( ((char*)temp + (temp->size)) == (char*)(temp->next)){
                printf("Entered the if statement\n");
                        temp->size += (temp->next)->size;
                temp->next = NULL;
        }


    }else {

        while(temp->next != NULL  ){

            if( ((char*)temp + (temp->size)) == (char*)(temp->next)){

                temp->size += (temp->next)->size;
                                printf("coalesced size is %d temp->size \n", temp->size);
                temp->next = (temp->next)->next;
                ((temp->next)->next)->prev = temp;
            }
            temp=temp->next;

        }

    }



}
```

The results is

```
Addr of temp is  7f9c1e89b070

Size of Temp is  200

Addr of end of temp free node space is  7f9c1e89b138

Addr of start temp->next  is  7f9c1e89b278
```

And as you see it never enters `if statement`. Also let me know if there's any other algorithm for memory coalescing which might be more efficient.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths `freep` is the pointer to the beginning of my free list

Comment: @MonaJalal why do you think you should enter in this if? did you debug code during adding of nodes and check if the last `else` part of the code do proper things?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `temp->size` in decimal here:

```
printf("Size of Temp is  %d\n\n", temp->size);
                         ^^
```

while you are printing out the pointer values in hex:

```
printf("Addr of temp is  %llx\n\n", (long long unsigned) temp);
                         ^^^^
```

`200` decimal is `C8` in hex and `0xC8` + `0x70` = `0x138`. So when you add `0xC8` to `0x7f9c1e89b070` the result is `0x7f9c1e89b138` which does not equal `0x7f9c1e89b278` and therefore you do not enter the *if* statement.

Comment: how should I make this line correct? `if( ((char*)temp + (temp->size)) == (char*)(temp->next))` I know the types are not consistent but I think the condition makes sense, right?

Comment: @MonaJalal I have looked at the code several times and there is just not enough information to determine how to make the code work as you expect. If the rest of the code works as expected then you may need to come up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and formulate a new question.